# Inferring simplest method to convert bit array 1 to bit array 2.

Tags: functions, boolean-algebra

Consider the set of all bit arrays of length $n$. Now consider the set of all 1-to-1 functions that map from this set to this set.

Now select a single function out of the latter set. Is there any algorithm to find a "minimal" method of implementing this function? Assume that we only have access to fundamental bit array operators such as AND OR XOR NOT and left and right bitshifts.

In case you're wondering, the reason I want this is because I'm writing an algorithm to convert from [z-curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) ordering of bits to [hilbert-curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) ordering of bits. My current method is to make a lookup table, but I bet there's a better option.

As a simple example, let's say I have a truth table that looks like this:

```
00 -> 10
01 -> 01
10 -> 00
11 -> 11
```

Then I should be able to infer that, given an input bit string `input`, the output bit string `output` is (in java syntax)

```
output = ((~input) << 1) ^ input
```

Here's the proof in this case:

```
00 -> 11 -> 10 -> 10
01 -> 10 -> 00 -> 01
10 -> 01 -> 10 -> 00
11 -> 00 -> 00 -> 11
```

Comment: You consider the *set* of all 1-to-1 functions, but then you ask about enacting this *function*. It is not clear just exactly which function you have in mind.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've made a little edit that should help. I'd left a sentence out!

Comment: There *is* an algorithm: enumerate all possible methods of implementing the function until you find one that works! But the most promising approach to solve your problem is probably to ask your question on a programming site, ideally one oriented towards scientific programming. I would be surprised if there isn't already a standard algorithm to do what you're trying to do!

Comment: Alright, [we'll see if that works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16533017/inferring-simplest-method-to-convert-bit-array-1-to-bit-array-2). But I suspect I'm kinda between the two sites here. :-/  I've added an example if that helps.

Comment: Funny, when I [shared the question on stack overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16533017/348056) the first comment that I got was that the problem was completely intractable.